# Why is the color property not changing on my <li> elements with my .hover() event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HUSTLE PAY$</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device - width, initial scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I want jquery to do for me is:

1. When you hover over an LI element, that elements background color should turn #0066cc (which works fine). However, I also want the font color changing to white upon the same hover. This is where my code fails because the font does not turn white.
2. The original color of the list should return back to normal when .hover no longer takes place.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('li').hover(function(){
           $(this).css({"background-color" : "#0066cc" , "color" :   "white"})
       },function(){
           $(this).css({"background-color" : "#0000cc" , "color" :  "black"})
       });

   })
   ```

I thought the bit of jquery script would do the job but it doesnt execute it properly. What am I missing to make this work for me?

```
    .menu{
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        width:10%;
    }

    ul{
        background-color:#0000cc;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid black;
        width:60%;
        height:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    li{
        border:1px solid red;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        height:30px;
        font-size:30px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    a{
        color:black;
    }

</style>
</head>

   <body>
      <header>
        <div>
            <img src = "greenProject/images/menu.jpeg" class = "menu" alt =  "Image not available">
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you not doing this via CSS in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The text color of the list item changes just fine, but that doesn't affect the text color of the links in the list items.

To set the text color of the links you would need to find them inside the list items:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "#0066cc" }).find('a').css({ "color" : "white" });
  },function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "#0000cc" }).find('a').css({ "color" : "black" });
  });
});
```

You can also do this in CSS instead of using a Javascript event:

```
li:hover {
  background: #0066cc;
}
li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```